# why this "sort" command not work?

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, sed

I want to sort this file:

```
[ichen@ui02 ~]$ cat file
root_1down 20 root_EG 1195597
root_2down 19 root_EG 1340493
root_2down 1 root_EG 4136169
```

I want the output is the number order,So this is the result I wanted:

```
root_1down 20 root_EG 1195597
root_2down 1 root_EG 4136169
root_2down 19 root_EG 1340493
```

So , How Can I Get The Right Order I Wanted?

```
**Supply:**
```

It successful according to the command by@Cyrus:`sort -t " " -k1,1 -k2,2n file`
But, when I Swap the value of first word and second word:

```
[ichen@ui05 ~]$ cat file
20 root_1down root_EG 1195597
19 root_2down root_EG 1340493
1 root_2down root_EG 4136169
```

This time I want to have the same result, I want sort first by the second word, then by the first, the output is expected the same as above. However, the output is not what I expected:

```
[ichen@ui05 ~]$ sort -t " "  -k2,1 -k1,2n file
1 root_2down root_EG 4136169
19 root_2down root_EG 1340493
20 root_1down root_EG 1195597
```

The second word is not sorted by the way I expected.

Comment: You want the result to be sorted first by the embedded number inside of the the first column then by the number in the second column?

Comment: @dawg not the embedded number, but the whole word include the number. In fact, There are thousands of lines, many of them have the different first word but same embedded number, so I want to sort by the whole first word

Comment: You swapped columns in file but not the sort keys (well, you swapped keys but not correctly!). `sort -t " "  -k2,2 -k1,1n file` should give expected output.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sort:

```
sort -t " " -k1,1 -k2,2n file
```

Output:

```
root_1down 20 root_EG 1195597
root_2down 1 root_EG 4136169
root_2down 19 root_EG 1340493
```

Comment: I edited the question, It's not work when I swapped the first word and second word, I used  the command `sort -t " "  -k2,1 -k1,2n file` the detail is on question updated. Could you have a look?

Comment: I suggest to rollback your change and start a new question.